# Accessing Nonstatic Member Function without Instantiated Object?

Tags: c++, syntax

I have a programming assignment that provides the driver as well as the method header that must be used. The issue is that the method is a member function and the driver does not instantiate an object of the function's class to call the function.

Function header:

```
template <class Comparable>
void mergesortImproved( vector<Comparable> &a ) { //solution here }
```

Driver (separate file) call to mergesortImproved:

```
mergesortImproved( items );
```

We aren't allowed to submit a modified driver, so it would seem this is supposed to work. Am I missing something, or is this just a sloppy assignment?

Comment: That's not a member function. There's no class being defined.

Comment: So what happened when you compiled it?

Comment: @PeteBecker I silently assumed that the class definition simply was left out. For me, it was clear from the context. Anything wrong about that?

Comment: @Aconcagua while it's possible the class definition was left out; it would be unusual to write `mergesortImproved( items )` and leave out `obj.` on the front. My guess would be that it is a non-member function and OP didn't understand what `template<class Comparable>` does. We'll have to wait for OP clarification.

Comment: @M.M my second sentence certainly states that this function is a member function.  Thank you, however, for bringing up the point that it's possible that this is not a member function, as I just noticed that there is no place for me to submit a .h file (meaning there is no class to be made). I suppose I was confused because the instructor never mentioned this and we have been previously required to create classes containing the implementations for all previous assignments.

Comment: @shtuken Thanks for clarification. Anyway - have a close look at your implementation. If if your mergesortImproved does *not* rely on any non-static members of its containing class, consider making it static. If it does *not* rely on any members of the class at all, consider making it the global function itself (instead of the wrapper I presented in my answer), and if the class does nothing else, drop it entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: This is not possible. A non-static member function cannot be called without associated object instance. Any non-static function implicitely has an additional parameter that must be passed with (e. g. a call to `o->f(10, 12)` is implicitely converted into something like `_f(o, 10, 12)`; if interested, have a look at [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#thiscall)).

A static member function still would have to be called via `classname::function()`, so again – bad luck.

But: you could place a global function into the header, which would instanciate the object and call the objects member function:

*.h:

```
class X
{
    template <class Comparable>
    void mergesortImproved( vector<Comparable> &a )
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}

template <class Comparable>
void mergesortImproved( vector<Comparable> &a )
{
    X x;
    x.mergesortImproved(a);
}
```